# cannot open 32bit instance of IE11 on windows 10

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-11

Earlier today I was able to open a 32 bit instance of internet explorer from C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe. Some automatic update happened, and now when I do the same thing a 64 bit version opens. Only solutions I've seen are modifying the registry (which I haven't tried). Not sure why I'd have to do this just to open a 32 bit IE11 instance. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Internet Explorer is a deprecated feature, which would have been removed altogether if it weren't for many internal components requiring it.

Comment: you might have better answers / resolutions if you asked over at [microsoft tech forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/home?category=internetexplorer)